# Apply multiple aggregations on multiple columns on a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
+-----------------------+
|  id  | weight | value |
+-----------------------+
|  i1  |   1    |   0   |
|  i1  |   2    |   3   |
|  i1  |   3    |   6   |
|  i2  |   1    |   2   |
|  i2  |   2    |   2   |
|  i3  |   2    |   2   |
+-----------------------+
```

and I would like to do a couple of aggregations to calculate the following per `id`:

- average weighted value
- total value
- number of values that are not zero

The expected output is like the following:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|  new_id  | avg_val | val_sum | val_count |
+------------------------------------------+
|    i1    |    4    |    9    |     2     |
|    i2    |    2    |    4    |     2     |
|    i3    |    2    |    2    |     1     |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Please notice that the `id` column name is an input which might be different or similar to the old one.

I know I can achieve this in multiple approaches, but what is the recommended and fastest one knowing that the amount of data we are dealing with is very big?

Possible solutions that came to my mind:

1. group and merge for every aggregation

   ```
   in_df = pd.DataFrame({
       'id': ['i1', 'i1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i2', 'i3'],
       'weight': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2],
       'value': [0, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2]
   })

   out_df = pd.DataFrame()
   out_df['new_id'] = in_df['id'].unique()

   grouped_df = in_df.groupby('id').apply(lambda group: (group['weight'] * group['value']).sum() / max(group['weight'].sum(), 0.001)).reset_index(name='avg_val')
   out_df = pd.merge(out_df,
                     grouped_df,
                     left_on='new_id',
                     right_on='id',
                     how='left')
   out_df.drop('id')  # Dangerous if the `new_id` name is similar to `id`

   # Go on like this for every aggregation ...

   print(out_df)
   ```
2. group and update for every aggregation

   ```
   in_df = pd.DataFrame({
       'id': ['i1', 'i1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i2', 'i3'],
       'weight': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2],
       'value': [0, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2]
   })

   out_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['new_id', 'avg_val', 'val_sum', 'val_count'])
   out_df['new_id'] = in_df['id'].unique()
   out_df = out_df.set_index('new_id')

   grouped_df = in_df.groupby('id').apply(lambda group: (group['weight'] * group['value']).sum() / max(group['weight'].sum(), 0.001)).reset_index(name='avg_val')
   grouped_df = grouped_df.set_index('id')

   out_df.update(grouped_df)

   # Go on like this for every aggregation ...

   print(out_df)
   ```

Comment: Can you explain how are you calculating your `avg_val` ?

Comment: I am dividing by the sum of weights instead of the count. This is one of our requirements. Sorry if the term was misleading

Comment: A'right. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
res = df.assign(wv = df['weight'].mul(df['value'])).groupby('id').agg({
    'wv': 'sum',
    'weight': 'sum',
    'value':['sum', np.count_nonzero]
})
res['avg_val'] = res['wv'] / res['weight']
res = res.drop(['wv', 'weight'],1) 
res.columns = ['val_sum', 'val_count', 'avg_val']
```

Output:

```
        val_sum  val_count  avg_val
  id                                 
  i1          9          2      4.0
  i2          4          2      2.0
  i3          2          1      2.0
```

Both of your questions use `apply` + `lambda`, so that you can loop over each group (among many other things) while this code does no such things. That is why it is faster and efficient.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer and explain why it is better than the two mentioned solutions (performance-wise) as this is the point of the question?

Comment: Both of your questions use `apply` + `lambda`, so that you can loop over each group  (among many other things) while this code does no such things. That is why it is faster and efficient. @Mousa

Comment: Please edit your answer with the provided information, just to make your answer complete for other interested people